# Where can I find a PDF of the documentation for JUJU?

Tags: juju

Is there a FULL PDF manual on the JUJU that can be printed as oppose to reading on the internet? I prefer a hard copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an amazing website for documenting JuJu which is [jujucharms.com](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started).

If you want a PDF, then you can read  [this PDF](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/juju-gui/latest/juju-gui.pdf).

Comment: I knew it. However i prefer a PDF Manual.

Comment: i also provided you a PDF link

Comment: The link you mentioned redirected me to https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started

Comment: Both the link redirected to the same page as i mentioned above

Comment: You should probably link to a newer version: http://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/14.04e2/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2014.04%20-%20Second%20edition.pdf

Comment: try it now. fixing link error

Comment: @muru Tq 4 the link. It is about Ubuntu Manual. I'm Looking for JUJU.

Comment: @AUmarMukthar I know. It's just a new version of the link NewUser originally had.